# MySQL row count

Tags: mysql, count, query-optimization

I have a very large table (~1 000 000 rows) and complicated query with unions, joins and where statements (user can select different ORDER BY columns and directions). I need to get a row count for pagination. If I run query without counting rows it completes very fast. How can I implement pagination in fastest way?
I tried to use EXPLAIN SELECT and SHOW TABLE STATUS to get approximate row count, but it is very different from real row count. 
My query is like this one (simplyfied):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (   
        SELECT * FROM table_1 
        LEFT JOIN `table_a` ON table_1.record_id = table_a.id 
        LEFT JOIN `table_b` ON table_a.id = table_b.record_id 
        WHERE table_1.a > 10 AND table_a.b < 500 AND table_b.c = 1 
        ORDER BY x ASC
        LIMIT 0, 10        
    )      
    UNION        
    (   
        SELECT * FROM table_2
        LEFT JOIN `table_a` ON table_2.record_id = table_a.id 
        LEFT JOIN `table_b` ON table_a.id = table_b.record_id 
        WHERE table_2.d < 10 AND table_a.e > 500 AND table_b.f = 1 
        ORDER BY x ASC
        LIMIT 0, 10                                 
    )                 
) tbl ORDER BY x ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Query result without limiting is about ~100 000 rows, how can I get this approximate count in fastest way?
My production query example is like this one:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (
    (   
        SELECT
          articles_log.id AS log_id, articles_log.source_table,
          articles_log.record_id AS id, articles_log.dat AS view_dat, 
          articles_log.lang AS view_lang, '1' AS view_count, '1' AS unique_view_count,
          articles_log.user_agent, articles_log.ref, articles_log.ip,
          articles_log.ses_id, articles_log.bot, articles_log.source_type, articles_log.link,   
          articles_log.user_country, articles_log.user_platform,
          articles_log.user_os, articles_log.user_browser,                                          
          `contents`.dat AS source_dat, `contents_trans`.header, `contents_trans`.custom_text 
        FROM articles_log 
        INNER JOIN `contents` ON articles_log.record_id = `contents`.id
                             AND articles_log.source_table = 'contents'  
        INNER JOIN `contents_trans` ON `contents`.id = `contents_trans`.record_id
                                   AND `contents_trans`.lang='lv' 
        WHERE articles_log.dat > 0
          AND articles_log.dat >= 1488319200
          AND articles_log.dat <= 1489355999
          AND articles_log.bot = '0'
          AND (articles_log.record_id NOT LIKE '%\_404' AND articles_log.record_id <> '404'
               OR articles_log.source_table <> 'contents') 
    )      
    UNION        
    (   
        SELECT
          articles_log.id AS log_id, articles_log.source_table,
          articles_log.record_id AS id, articles_log.dat AS view_dat, 
          articles_log.lang AS view_lang, '1' AS view_count, '1' AS unique_view_count,
          articles_log.user_agent, articles_log.ref, articles_log.ip,
          articles_log.ses_id, articles_log.bot,
          articles_log.source_type, articles_log.link,   
          articles_log.user_country, articles_log.user_platform,
          articles_log.user_os, articles_log.user_browser,                                          
        `news`.dat AS source_dat, `news_trans`.header, `news_trans`.custom_text 
        FROM articles_log 
        INNER JOIN `news` ON articles_log.record_id = `news`.id
                         AND articles_log.source_table = 'news'  
        INNER JOIN `news_trans` ON `news`.id = `news_trans`.record_id
                         AND `news_trans`.lang='lv' 
        WHERE articles_log.dat > 0 
          AND articles_log.dat >= 1488319200
          AND articles_log.dat <= 1489355999
          AND articles_log.bot = '0'
          AND (articles_log.record_id NOT LIKE '%\_404' AND articles_log.record_id <> '404'
               OR articles_log.source_table <> 'contents') 
    )      
) tbl ORDER BY view_dat ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x = ...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x`

Comment: I would do it in two different queries. That way it will be cleanest and I think the fastest solution.

Comment: is using COUNT(*) really that slow?

Comment: I really need UNION. And two different queries works the same speed. Yes, COUNT(*) is really slowing query. Is it possible to get approximate count?

Comment: Can you use UNION ALL?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, thanks, now it is 2x faster (60 secs -> 30 secs). But still 30 secs is a long execution time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` (which is a shortcut for `UNION DISTINCT`) - In other words - If you don't need to remove duplicates you can try to add the counts of the two subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    (   
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 
        LEFT JOIN `table_a` ON table_1.record_id = table_a.id 
        LEFT JOIN `table_b` ON table_a.id = table_b.record_id 
        WHERE table_1.a > 10 AND table_a.b < 500 AND table_b.c = 1      
    )      
    +
    (   
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2
        LEFT JOIN `table_a` ON table_2.record_id = table_a.id 
        LEFT JOIN `table_b` ON table_a.id = table_b.record_id 
        WHERE table_2.d < 10 AND table_a.e > 500 AND table_b.f = 1                              
    ) 
    AS cnt
```

Without `ORDER BY` and without `UNION` the engine might not need to create a huge temp table.

**Update**

For your original query try the following:

- Select only `count(*)`.
- Remove `OR articles_log.source_table <> 'contents'` from first part (contents) since we know it's never true.
- Remove `AND (articles_log.record_id NOT LIKE '%\_404' AND articles_log.record_id <> '404' OR articles_log.source_table <> 'contents')` from second part (news) since we know it's allways true because `OR articles_log.source_table <> 'contents'` is allways true.
- Remove the joins with `contents` and `news`. You can join the `*_trans` tables directly using `record_id`
- Remove `articles_log.dat > 0` since it's redundant with `articles_log.dat >= 1488319200`

The resulting query:

```
SELECT (   
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM articles_log 
    INNER JOIN `contents_trans`
      ON `contents_trans`.record_id = articles_log.record_id
      AND `contents_trans`.lang='lv' 
    WHERE articles_log.bot = '0'
      AND articles_log.dat >= 1488319200
      AND articles_log.dat <= 1489355999
      AND articles_log.record_id NOT LIKE '%\_404'
      AND articles_log.record_id <> '404'
) + (   
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM articles_log 
    INNER JOIN `news_trans`
      ON  `news_trans`.record_id = articles_log.record_id
      AND `news_trans`.lang='lv' 
    WHERE articles_log.bot = '0'
      AND articles_log.dat >= 1488319200
      AND articles_log.dat <= 1489355999
) AS cnt
```

Try the following index combinations:

```
articles_log(bot, dat, record_id)
contents_trans(lang, record_id)
news_trans(lang, record_id)
```

or

```
contents_trans(lang, record_id)
news_trans(lang, record_id)
articles_log(record_id, bot, dat)
```

It depends on the data, which combination ist the better one.

I might be wrong on one ore more points, since i don't know your data and business logic. If so, try to adjust the other.

Comment: Thanks! 4 times faster with this construction.

Comment: 4 times faster - So still like 15 seconds?

Comment: Yes, query executes about 15 seconds. But it is better than 60.

Comment: @Unibit This is too much for "only" 100K rows (IMHO). Maybe you are missing some usefull indexes. Check the update.

Comment: The most "expensive" WHERE condition is articles_log.bot, but there could be just two values: 0 and 1 (about 50% of rows are "0" and about 50% are "1"). Adding index on this column doesn't solve the problem. Other your mentioned columns are indexed.

Comment: I also couldn't JOIN *_trans tables directly because of I need info from "not _trans" tables, there also could be WHERE condition on these tables.

Comment: `(bot, dat, record_id)` is definitely better -- First `=`, then useful range, finally 'covering'.

Comment: @Unibit - Those are _composite_ indexes, not separate 1-column indexes.

Comment: @RickJames If `lang` is more selective than the `(bot, dat)` combination, `(record_id, bot, dat)` or `(bot, record_id, dat)` would be needed for the reversed join order.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - "Selectivity" and "cardinality" are overrated.  Starting with the `bot=constant` is far more important for speeding up the query -- because it will end up scanning fewer rows (of the index).  `dat` needs to be next because it is a simple range.  `record_id` is there only for "covering".

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - To get some numbers:  `FLUSH STATUS;  SELECT ...;`  SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`  (Do that with the index in one order, then in another order.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the calculation when you run the query using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` as explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
. . .
```

And then running:

```
select FOUND_ROWS()
```

However, the first run needs to generate all the data, so you are going to get up to 20 possible rows -- I don't think it respects `LIMIT` in subqueries.

Given the structure of your query and you want to do, I would think first about optimizing the query.  For instance, is `UNION` really needed (it incurs overhead for removing duplicates)?  As pointed out in a comment, your joins are really inner joins disguised as outer joins.  Indexes might improve performance.

You might want to ask another question, providing sample data and desired results to get advice on such issues.

Comment: At this moment I use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and it takes about 60 secs to complete (without LIMIT in subqueries). My posted query completes in 0.01 secs. Yes, I really need UNION. Yes, I use indexes. It is working slow with INNER and LEFT join.

Comment: I added production query example to my question.

Comment: The keywords `INNER` and `OUTER` are noise -- MySQL ignores them since the effect is _identical_.